# How to validate based on specific Enum member in a Fastapi Pydantic model

Tags: python, validation, enums, fastapi, pydantic

Here is my Pydantic model:

```py
from enum import Enum
from pydantic import BaseModel


class ProfileField(str, Enum):
    mobile = "mobile"
    email = "email"
    address = "address"
    interests ="interests"  # need list of strings


class ProfileType(str, Enum):
    primary = "primary"
    secondary = "secondary"


class ProfileDetail(BaseModel):
    name: ProfileField
    value: str
    type: ProfileType
```

My API is accepting this type of JSON and its working fine.

```json
{
    "data": [
        {
            "name": "email",
            "value": "abcd@gmail.com",
            "type": "primary"
        }
    ]
}
```

**The requirement is `email` is string type and needs a regex, `mobile` is integer type and also needs a regex, and `address` is a string and needs to be restricted to 50 characters.**

Is it possible to add corresponding validations?

Comment: You can to use pydantic validation for your example https://docs.pydantic.dev/usage/validators/

Comment: _"mobile is integer type and also needs a regex"_ Doubt it. Regex on integers is a new one for me. Besides, phone numbers should probably not be stored as integers anyway. Leading zeros might matter, don't you think?

Comment: yes mobile is not int its str and mistake from my end

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Discriminated union and built-in types/validators

If I understand correctly, the actual JSON data you receive has the top-level `data` key and its value is an array of objects that you currently represent with your `ProfileDetail` schema.

If that is the case, you may be better served by not using an `Enum` at all for your `name` field and instead defining a [discriminated union](https://docs.pydantic.dev/usage/types/#discriminated-unions-aka-tagged-unions) based on the value of the `name` field. You can write a separate model for each case (`mobile`, `email`, and `address`) and delegate validation to each of them for their own case.

Since all three of them share a base schema, you can define a base model for them to inherit from to reduce repetition. The `type` field for example can stay an `Enum` (Pydantic handles validation of those [out of the box](https://docs.pydantic.dev/usage/types/#enums-and-choices)) and can be inherited by the three submodels.

For `mobile` and `address` it sounds like you can just use [`constr`](https://docs.pydantic.dev/usage/types/#arguments-to-constr) to define your constraints via the `regex` and `max_length` parameters respectively.

For `email`, you can use the built-in Pydantic type [`EmailStr`](https://docs.pydantic.dev/usage/types/#pydantic-types) (subtype of `str`). You'll just need to install the optional dependency with `pip install 'pydantic[email]'`.

That way you should not even need to write any custom validators.

Here is the setup I suggest:

```py
from enum import Enum
from typing import Annotated, Literal, Union
from pydantic import BaseModel, EmailStr, Field, constr

class ProfileType(str, Enum):
    primary = "primary"
    secondary = "secondary"

class BaseProfileFieldData(BaseModel):
    value: str
    type: ProfileType

class MobileData(BaseProfileFieldData):
    value: constr(regex=r"\d{5,}")  # your actual regex here
    name: Literal["mobile"]

class EmailData(BaseProfileFieldData):
    value: EmailStr
    name: Literal["email"]

class AddressData(BaseProfileFieldData):
    value: constr(max_length=50)
    name: Literal["address"]

ProfileField = Annotated[
    Union[MobileData, EmailData, AddressData],
    Field(discriminator="name")
]

class ProfileDetails(BaseModel):
    data: list[ProfileField]
```

---

### Tests

Let's test it with some fixtures:

```py
test_data_mobile_valid = {
  "name": "mobile",
  "value": "123456",
  "type": "secondary",
}
test_data_mobile_invalid = {
  "name": "mobile",
  "value": "12",
  "type": "secondary",
}
test_data_email_valid = {
  "name": "email",
  "value": "abcd@gmail.com",
  "type": "primary",
}
test_data_email_invalid = {
  "name": "email",
  "value": "abcd@gmail@..",
  "type": "primary",
}
test_data_address_valid = {
  "name": "address",
  "value": "some street 42, 12345 example",
  "type": "secondary",
}
test_data_address_invalid = {
  "name": "address",
  "value": "x" * 51,
  "type": "secondary",
}
test_data_invalid_name = {
  "name": "foo",
  "value": "x",
  "type": "primary",
}
test_data_invalid_type = {
  "name": "mobile",
  "value": "123456",
  "type": "bar",
}
```

The first six should be self explanatory. `test_data_invalid_name` should cause an error because `"foo"` is not a valid discriminator value for `name`. `test_data_invalid_type` should demonstrate the built-in enum validator catching the invalid `type` value `"bar"`.

Let's test the valid data first:

```py
if __name__ == "__main__":
    from pydantic import ValidationError

    obj = ProfileDetails.parse_obj({
        "data": [
            test_data_mobile_valid,
            test_data_email_valid,
            test_data_address_valid,
        ]
    })
    print(obj.json(indent=4))
    ...
```

Output:

```json
{
    "data": [
        {
            "value": "123456",
            "type": "secondary",
            "name": "mobile"
        },
        {
            "value": "abcd@gmail.com",
            "type": "primary",
            "name": "email"
        },
        {
            "value": "some street 42, 12345 example",
            "type": "secondary",
            "name": "address"
        }
    ]
}
```

No surprises here. Now test those that should not pass the `value` validation:

```py
if __name__ == "__main__":
    ...
    try:
        ProfileDetails.parse_obj({
            "data": [
                test_data_mobile_invalid,
                test_data_email_invalid,
                test_data_address_invalid,
            ]
        })
    except ValidationError as exc:
        print(exc.json(indent=4))
    ...
```

Output:

```json
[
    {
        "loc": [
            "data",
            0,
            "MobileData",
            "value"
        ],
        "msg": "string does not match regex \"\\d{5,}\"",
        "type": "value_error.str.regex",
        "ctx": {
            "pattern": "\\d{5,}"
        }
    },
    {
        "loc": [
            "data",
            1,
            "EmailData",
            "value"
        ],
        "msg": "value is not a valid email address",
        "type": "value_error.email"
    },
    {
        "loc": [
            "data",
            2,
            "AddressData",
            "value"
        ],
        "msg": "ensure this value has at most 50 characters",
        "type": "value_error.any_str.max_length",
        "ctx": {
            "limit_value": 50
        }
    }
]
```

Caught all the wrong values. Now just to be sure, the last two fixtures:

```py
if __name__ == "__main__":
    ...
    try:
        ProfileDetails.parse_obj({
            "data": [
                test_data_invalid_name,
                test_data_invalid_type,
            ]
        })
    except ValidationError as exc:
        print(exc.json(indent=4))
```

Output:

```json
[
    {
        "loc": [
            "data",
            0
        ],
        "msg": "No match for discriminator 'name' and value 'foo' (allowed values: 'mobile', 'email', 'address')",
        "type": "value_error.discriminated_union.invalid_discriminator",
        "ctx": {
            "discriminator_key": "name",
            "discriminator_value": "foo",
            "allowed_values": "'mobile', 'email', 'address'"
        }
    },
    {
        "loc": [
            "data",
            1,
            "MobileData",
            "type"
        ],
        "msg": "value is not a valid enumeration member; permitted: 'primary', 'secondary'",
        "type": "type_error.enum",
        "ctx": {
            "enum_values": [
                "primary",
                "secondary"
            ]
        }
    }
]
```

Seems like we get the desired behavior from our model.

---

### Caveat

If you really want a separate model like the `ProfileDetail` you showed in your question, that will not be possible with discriminated unions because those rely on being defined for a **field** on a separate model. In that case you'll actually have to write a custom validator (probably a [`root_validator`](https://docs.pydantic.dev/usage/validators/#root-validators)) to ensure consistency between `name` and `value`.

Comment: Thanks Daniil Fajnberg its worked and one small correction for others ( for python 3.9 above this will work and below 3.9 "1) from typing_extensions import Annotated, Literal, 2) from typing import Union, List,    class ProfileDetails(BaseModel):
    data: List[ProfileField]" )

Comment: But here the value str we defined how can make it accept different data types.
[class BaseProfileFieldData(BaseModel):
    value: str
    type: ProfileType]